# exception calling open with 0 argument(s)

Tags: oracle, powershell, ms-access

I'm using powershell and I'm trying to connect to a MS Access .mdb file and also connect to my Oracle SQL Developer database (because I want to pull data from an access table and insert it into an Oracle Developer table). But I have the error **exception calling open with 0 argument(s)** when opening the connection with both applications.

This is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient

# Connection string to Access database
$accessConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MyFolder\Documents\ACC_BASE.MDB;Persist Security Info=False;"

# Connection string to Oracle database
$oracleConnString = "Data Source=MyConnection;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;"

# SQL query to select data from Access table
$query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_PREV"

# Create Access database connection
$accessConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($accessConnString)

# Create Oracle database connection
$oracleConn = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($oracleConnString)

# Open Access database connection
$accessConn.Open()

# Execute Access query
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($query, $accessConn)
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

# Open Oracle database connection
$oracleConn.Open()
```

Comment: I think you have two separate issues.  In both cases the connection string is the root cause.  The connection is null and calling open with null is giving the error.  The Oracle is probably using a ODBC connection and MyConnection is not defined in the ODBC. From Window Start Button type "ODBC Data Source" and moke sure MyConnection is defined.  With Access you need Access installed on machine or the RunTime version of ACE.  The version number 12 has to match the version of office on machine.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is **NOT** a database it is a user interface that is used to connect to (many) databases.